# What is the reason for section 1 of LGPL and what is the implication for section 9.

Tags: lgpl

Why was section 1 added to LGPLv3? My understanding of section 3&4 is, one can convey the combined work under any license and with no requirements from GPLv3 (besides those explicitly stated as requirements in LGPLv3 3&4). Given that, why is section 1 necessary. Wouldn't that sections 3&4 by themselves already imply anyhow what section 1 explicitly states?

I assume that I'm missing something and section 1 isn't redundant. Assuming that, does this have implications for other sections in GPLv3? E.g. does conveying a covered work under sections 3&4 fall under the  patent clause of section 10 of GPLv3? Why does section 1 not also state an exception for section 10?

Put another way. Is the [Eigen FAQ](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Licensing_FAQ#So_what_does_the_LGPL_require_me_to_do.3F) correct by stating:

> LGPL requires [for header only libraries] pretty much the same as the 2-clause BSD license.

It it true that for  conveying object files including material from LGPLv3 headers no GPLv3 patent clauses apply?

Comment: Some answers to 'why?' questions can be found in the GPLv3 FAQ (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html).   There may also be some illuminating information in the notes at http://gplv3.fsf.org/discussion-committees/D

Answer (score 1):

Here's why.  It's due to the opening of the [LGPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html).

`This version of the GNU Lesser General Public License incorporates the terms and conditions of version 3 of the GNU General Public License, supplemented by the additional permissions listed below.`

As an answer, that's admittedly a little opaque.  But when we look at Section 1  of the LGPL v3 again, it starts to be a little more clear.

```
1. Exception to Section 3 of the GNU GPL.

You may convey a covered work under sections 3 and 4 of this License without being 
bound by section 3 of the GNU GPL.
```

The opening of the LGPL v3 incorporates all of [GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) into itself.  But that creates a problem since Section 3 of the GPL v3: `When you convey a covered work, you waive any legal power to forbid circumvention of technological measures ...` may run counter to your intent with using the LGPL.

Section 1 of the LGPL v3.0 was put in there to bypass that particular restriction.  LGPL v3 Section 4 discusses reverse engineering for debugging purposes, but GPL v3 Section 3 is much broader in its context.  LGPL v3 Sections 3 & 4 do not create the same restrictions, so they are not equivalent to Section 3 of GPL v3.

Regarding the patent clauses (Sections 10 & 11 of GPL v3): They are in full effect for LGPL v3 and the LGPL V3 Section 1 exception does not apply to them.  Conveying a work through LGPL v3 Sections 3 & 4 has no bearing upon the restrictions created from GPL v3 Sections 10 & 11.

LGPL incorporates the GPL in order to simplify maintaining the licenses.  I can't answer for certain why there isn't an exception clause similar to LGPL v3 Section 1.  However, since the FSF opposes software patents, I can't see them providing an exception to the automatic patent licensing that GPL v3 Section 10 provides.  They want less patents and entanglements, not more.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235656/1345223) from SO tipped me off to the [major differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1108238/1345223) between LGPL v2.1 and v3.0